# How Do I programatically show/hide an item in Xamarin.Forms Shell Framework?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am working on some code to populate a Flyout Menu in Xamarin.Forms' new Shell Framework. I know how to create the objects themselves in XAML, but I can't figure out how to dynamically show/hide options.

I've tried a few different solutions, and setting visibility works (but it doesn't feel as efficient as it should be, since it requires a massive collection of #if statements to be processed at run time.

This is the basic Shell Item with naming and routing conventions for mapping the navigation.

```
<ShellItem x:Name="home"
               Route="home"
               Title="Home">
        <ShellSection>
            <ShellContent>
                <local:ItemsPage/>
            </ShellContent>
        </ShellSection>
    </ShellItem>
```

Ideally, I'm hoping for either a way to dynamically hide the Shell Items, or a way to build the menu quicker based on the return from my API.

Does anyone have some ideas how to accomplish a dynamic menu at run time?

Comment: As per this issue: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/5428 this is not possible (out of the box) at the moment

Comment: Thank you @GeraldVersluis - That would explain why I couldn't wrap my head around why it wasn't working.

Comment: `IsInvisible` is now available for `ShellItem` you can bind it and play with it.